# elipsis dots after UITextfield for secured text entry

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitextfield

I have multiple uitextfields setup and they are all connected with IBOutlets. I have one textfield that is a password and I have the 'Secure text Entry' selected. when I have this check I get this[image]

Any ideas why this happens? If i deselect the secured entry the textfield rises fine depending on the size of the password with no ellipsis dots.

It does not matter how long the password is. Same thing.
[image: longer password]

If i don't have the security text selected it works fine
[image: no security selected]

Any idea why? It can be a width issue because it does autosize. But why does the 'secure text entry' cause the issue?

Comment: may be your UITextField don't have enough width

Comment: Well that is what I was thinking too. But it works fine if I toggle with regular text. So the with is fine with that.

Comment: Also it doesn't matter how long the password is. The width of the text field expands but always cuts the end

Comment: Add some UIColor to the background of UITextView and see what happens when you keep adding your password characters. What are your constraints on UITextView?

Comment: The fix I came up with was to pin the textfield to the width of the screen so I don't have to worry about the field resizing.

Comment: Is elipsis dots issue fixed then?

Comment: I figured out a different way but never solved the original issue of why the textfield cut the end off when using the secured text entry.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. I think it is a bug of UITextfield. It calculates size for the text but not for the secure text(dots). I have the problem when the text includes slim characters like 1, l etc...

As workaround I have subclassed the UITextfield class and overridden intrinsicContentSize function. You might need to adjust letter spacing. I couldn't find how to get it dynamically depending on font.

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {

    let size = super.intrinsicContentSize
    if !self.isSecureTextEntry {
      return size
    }

    var width = size.width
    if let font = self.font,
    let charCount = self.text?.count {
      width = "•".size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : font]).width * CGFloat(charCount)
      width += (CGFloat(charCount)+1) * 4.5 // this magic number is for letter spacing
    }
    return CGSize(width: width, height: size.height)
}
```